# Condition for an equivalence of functor categories

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, enriched-category-theory, equivalence-of-categories, morita-equivalence

Given small categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, we have that  $[\mathcal{C}^\text{op},\textbf{Set}]\simeq[\mathcal{D}^\text{op},\textbf{Set}]$ [if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819171/an-equivalence-of-categories-of-presheaves) the Cauchy-completions of $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are equivalent. If we replace $\textbf{Set}$ with an arbitrary topos $\mathscr{S}$, is there an equivalent condition for their functor categories into $\mathscr{S}$ to be equivalent?

The Cauchy completeness of $\mathcal{C}$ can be defined (for example in ncatlab) as the full subcategory of the category of presheaves on $\mathcal{C}$ on the retracts of representable functors. "Representable functors" only exist from $\mathcal{C}^\text{op}$ to $\textbf{Set}$ because $\mathcal{C}$ is enriched over $\textbf{Set}$, so does there need to be a similar condition on $\mathscr{S}$?

Comment: Welcome. Just fyi questions like this sometimes do better on MO than on MSE. If in a few days this question is still 'ignored', migrating it might be worth a shot

Comment: The empty topos is a topos and in that case the condition is trivial. So, clearly, the condition depends on $\mathcal{S}$. On the other hand, if $\mathcal{S}$ is "big" enough then $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ will be internalisable in $\mathcal{S}$, and I expect the answer to be basically the same as the classical case. (There may be a subtlety in the definition of "Cauchy completion", however.)

Comment: I would be happy restricting to the case where $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are internalisable in $\mathcal{S}$. Cauchy completion has a few (usually) equivalent definitions: for example, the full subcategory of $[\mathcal{C}^\text{op},\textbf{Set}]$ of _tiny objects_.